# Windows Bat: Loop a Padded Range

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

EDIT:
I need to a bat script ( or one-liner) to loop through a range which is given as a padded value. It will:

1. Unpad the values for start and end
2. iterate through a range given an unpadded value
3. that value needs to be re-padded again

For instance: start=0980 and end=1000 and step=1
I need to loop through that range and given a padded number back out.

I have this much but I keep getting:

```
(
SET VAR=000985
SET VAR=~-4
ECHO
)
ECHO is on.
```

What I have so far:

```
REM Get the start, end and step values
SET start=0980
SET end=0985
SET step=1

REM Remove Padding
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%A IN ("%start%") DO (SET start=%%A)
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%A IN ("%end%") DO (SET end=%%A)
FOR /l %%x in (%start%, %step%, %end%) DO ( 
    SET VAR=000%%x
    SET VAR=%VAR:~-4%
    ECHO %VAR%
)
```

Eventually VAR will be feed into a command

```
mantra -V a -F /some/path/with.%x.ifd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM Get the start, end and step values
SET /a start=980
SET /a end=985
SET /a step=1

REM Remove Padding
FOR /l %%x in (%start%, %step%, %end%) DO ( 
    SET VAR=000%%x
    SET VAR=!VAR:~-4!
    ECHO !VAR!
)
```

Delayedexpansion is the key - Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note the use of `set /a` since the values to be assigned are pure numeric. Unfortunately, leading zeroes imply the value is `OCTAL` so dispose of those.

Many, many articles on SO about delayedexpansion...look around.

Comment: thanks! unfortunately, when 'start' and 'end' get assigned later ( via %1, %2) they will be padded. I have no control over that! But that really helped thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. I don't understand if you need a solution that performs *precisely* the steps described (unpad values, iterate, re-pad value) or that generate a list of padded numbers no matter the method used; also, you did *not* shown what is the required output, so I assumed that is this list: `0980 0981 0982 0983 0984 0985`. Finally, you had not indicated the number of digits in the padded numbers, so I assumed it is 4 and that the input data have that number of digits or more.

This is a simple solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Get the start, end and step values as padded numbers
SET start=0980
SET end=0985
SET step=1

rem Convert the start and end values into an equivalent "1+N-digits" number (4 in this case)
rem for example: start=10980 and end=10985
set /A start=1%start:~-4%, end=1%end:~-4%

rem Iterate through the new range: from 10980 step 1 to 10985
for /L %%i in (%start%, %step%, %end%) do (
   rem Output the digits after the first one; for example: 0980, 0981, etc
   echo !start:~1!
   rem Pass to next number
   set /A start+=step
)
```